# Git Bash "If" AND "For" logic in same script seems to be incorrect

Tags: git, bash, bitbucket, git-bash

I have a script that loops through all of my bitbucket repositories and it is supposed to clone it if it doesn't exist locally and pull it if it does. Lets say i dont have any of the directories needed. I can run the script below and everything works correctly. If i run the same script again, it is still hitting the first part of the if statement and saying "the destination already exists and is not an empty repository". Now lets say i get rid of the "!", it now hits the second part of the logic for everything. This isnt making sense to me. Im new to git bash so any help would be appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash
#script to get all repositories under a user from bitbucket
#Usage: getAllRepos.sh [user]

curl -u user https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/users/user > repoinfo
for repo_name in $(grep -oE '\"slug\": "[^"]*"' repoinfo | cut -f4 -d\")
do
if [ ! -d "$repo_name" ];  then

git clone "git@bitbucket.org:user/$repo_name.git" "C:\\Users\\user\\.ssh\\$repo_name"

else 

git pull "git@bitbucket.org:user/$repo_name.git"

fi
done
```

I have updated the code to include corrections from the website recommended and it is still not working.

Comment: just an aside.. i don't think it's a great idea to be cloning into a ".ssh" folder.

Comment: Parsing JSON with grep and cut is so very, very wrong. For your sanity and mine, use jq: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: Also, there are a whole lot of bugs in here that http://shellcheck.net/ will catch

Comment: ...and you can't use a *backslash* as a separator in a `cd` command. This is UNIX, not Windows.

Comment: It looks like the script is checking for the existence of a directory in `C:\\Users\\username\\.ssh`, but cloning into `C:\\Users\\username\\.ssh\\Droids` - if you fix that discrepancy it ought to work.

Comment: i actually changed the code i have to make it easier to read, but i will edit it to be what is going on.

Comment: ...btw, there's no reason to use a `repoinfo` tempfile, unless you're running this under a version of Cygwin where process substitution is broken.

Comment: BTW, don't use `.sh` extensions for shell scripts. Executable files don't have extensions on UNIX. `.sh` extensions are appropriate for shell *libraries* compatible with POSIX sh, and `.bash` extensions are appropriate for shell *libraries* compatible with bash, but just as you don't run `ls.elf`, you shouldn't require your users to run `getAllRepos.sh` as opposed to just `getAllRepos`.

Comment: im running this in windows btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
die() { echo "ERROR: $*" >&2; exit 1; }

user=${1:-Monzingo}

mkdir -p ~/repos || die "Destination directory does not exist and could not be created"
cd ~/repos || die "Could not cd to destination directory"

while read -r repo_name <&3; do
  repo_name=${repo_name%$'\r'} # handle DOS newlines in input stream
  if [ -d "$repo_name" ]; then
    (cd "$repo_name" && exec git pull)
  else
    git clone "git@bitbucket.org:$user/$repo_name.git" "$repo_name"
  fi
done 3< <(curl -u "$user" "https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/users/$user" \
            | jq -r '.repositories[].slug')
```

---

In order to run this, you'll need to install [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). It's available prebuilt for Windows (including cygwin), and is a far, far saner way of parsing JSON.

Now, specifically, what are the differences?

- Changing the current directory to be just above the destination directory, and scoping any future directory changes to only occur within a subshell, means that your `test -d` is checking for whether a repository already exists in the same place where it would actually be created on checkout.
- ...to be specific: `(cd foo && exec bar)` scopes the change into directory `foo` into a subshell (not changing the working directory for the rest of the script), and executes `bar` inside that subshell only if the `cd` succeeded. The `exec` keyword is a minor performance optimization, terminating the subshell when `bar` is started [by replacing its process image with that of the program being started] rather than potentially forking off a new process for `bar` to run in.
- We're using forward slashes. Backslashes are a Windowsism, and Windows ports of bash support it only sporadically.
- We aren't using a temporary file; instead, we're using process substitution: `<(...)` is replaced with filename which can be used to access the output of the command `...`, in this case a `curl | jq` pipeline.
- We're changing current working directory to the location under which you're placing your repositories (**don't** use `~/.ssh` -- this directory is special, and OpenSSH places numerous requirements on its file permissions that can make it unsuitable for other purposes).

Comment: Use `bash -x scriptname` to execute it, and take note of the exact commands run when failures occur. If you run `PS4=':$LINENO+' bash -x scriptname`, that'll even include the line number for each command in that log.

Comment: ...also, exactly which build of bash you're running matters; some of the Windows builds don't correctly support process substitution.

Comment: do you need the tick at the end of slug?

Comment: Was missing another one before the beginning. Edited it in now.

Comment: ...btw, if your bash gives you a syntax error at the process substitution, you can restructure things to avoid needing it: `curl ... | jq | while read -r repo_name; do ...; done` -- that has the caveats given in BashFAQ #24, at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024, but those caveats don't actually matter so much for what you're doing right now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103655/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-monz).